# Key-value pair to column in SQL without stating columns

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, key-value, dynamic-sql

I have a table in AWS Redshift that has a wide variety of keys in the key-value pairs. I'm trying to convert this table to a more traditional structure where each of those unique keys are a column.

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         ID          |       Key           |        Value     |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          a          |          1          |         one      |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          a          |          2          |         two      |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          a          |          3          |         three    |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         ...         |          ...        |         ...      |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

to

```
|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|        Id       |        1        |      2       |      3       |      ...     |
|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|        a        |       one       |      two     |     three    |      ...     |
|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

However, I'm only finding solutions online where you have to explicitly type out each of the potential values of keys.  Manually coding these columns does not seem like a feasible solution for me as there are 200+ different keys already and that number is constantly increasing.

Is there any way I can dynamically generate the sql code to make this transformation using sql?

I can make a separate table of all the unique keys if that helps but I'm still not seeing a way to tie that into a SQL query.

Comment: "* I'm only finding solutions online where you have to explicitly type out each of the potential values of keys*" - because that's the only way you can do it

Comment: I work mostly with python so I'm not used to these types of limitations. I may just have to approach the problem a different way.

Comment: The main issue is that the data requires columns to be created in the database table. Thus, the columns with the appropriate names need to be created first, then the data needs to be converted into the new format. You could potentially write a Stored Procedure that look at the Key, checks if there is a column, adds the column if it doesn't exist, then inserts the data. It would be rather slow since each row would need to be independently processed.

Comment: Have a look at the [dbt](getdbt.com) project. It's an sql + python + jinja base tool for data transformation. It supports for example [the pivot operation](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-utils#pivot-source) (that's what you need). But If your pivot is the only transformation you need, then the structure dbt enforces may be an overkill.